# How to use a extension's function inside a view?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, ldap, flask-login

I want to use a function from a defined extension inside a view. I thought that `init_app()` should solve this issue.

This is my `app.py`

```
from flask_ldap3_login import LDAP3LoginManager
from flask_login import LoginManager

login_manager = LoginManager()
ldap_manager = LDAP3LoginManager()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_json('config.json')

    register_extensions(app)

    return app

def register_extensions(app):
     login_manager.init_app(app)
     ldap_manager.init_app(app)
```

And now I want to use at a `views.py` the `ldap_manager.authenticate()`.

```
def login():
    ldap_manager.authenticate('user', 'password')
```

This is my project structure:

```
app.py
  - main
      - __init__.py
      - views.py
```

How is this possible? I want to use this [example](https://flask-ldap3-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html#basic-application), but better structured.

Comment: `load_user` is not a view function, why do you want to put it into `views.py`?

Comment: You are right. But what is with for example with ``ldap_manager.authentication``?.

Comment: using `from app import ldap_manager` in your `views.py` didn't work?